# Adding Sin/Cos waves to a view

Tags: android

Is there a way to have a View in my XML file which builds graphs, based on different input from the user? All the graphs should be sin/cos waves....I have asked this on here before but the responses I received don't seem to cover Sin/Cos waves, just simple line graphs. I was told about achartengine, and Google Chart Tools.

Comment: It would probably help people answer you if you posted what you've tried, the code for how you're actually drawing your charts, and definitely more details of you issue.

Comment: I don't know what else to add....I need to have a View which displays a graph, which will be a sin wave. I have a sin function, and I need to graph it. I need to make a graph, using a sin function.

Comment: You ask me to show the code for me trying to draw my charts, but to my knowledge there is no such code. I'm assuming there must be some kind of package to download or a library to access, but I cannot find it. I don't believe that there is no way to display sin/cos graphs.

Comment: Well if you have the function for the data you're trying to display, why not just use the Canvas and draw the data points from the function?

Comment: I don't know what "the Canvas" is, I've been using Android for three weeks now.

Comment: That may have been the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Here's a decent tutorial for it: http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/06/drawing-with-canvas-in-android.html   That's what you want, and PS: Google helps a lot

Comment: thanks, if you could post this as an answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the function for the data you're trying to display, you can use the Canvas to plot the data points you want:

Canvas Tutorial: https://web.archive.org/web/20201026064852/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/06/drawing-with-canvas-in-android.html

Answer (score 2):

You can download the AChartEngine demo [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list) and give it a try.
There is [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/XYChartBuilder.java) part of the demo that does exactly what you need.